# Changing Radio Buttons when Drop Down Changes MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC view, I have a drop down list and three radio buttons, as given

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClientDur1.LookupValueID, "true", new { Name = "grp", @id = "CM1", @checked = "true" }) @Model.ClientDur1.Val1
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClientDur2.LookupValueID, "false", new { Name = "grp", @id = "CM2" })  @Model.ClientDur2.Val1
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClientDur3.LookupValueID, "false", new { Name = "grp", @id = "CM3" }) @Model.ClientDur3.Val3
```

and my Drop down list is,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Currency, new SelectList(Model.CurrencyList, "AttributeValueID", "AttributeDescription"), new { @id = "ddCurrencyId" })
```

And what I need is when ever I changes my dropdown List I would Like to update my Radio Button Values, That is my Model.ClientDur1.LookupValueID and ClientDur1.Val1 (similarly for others too) should have new changed details.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answer above:

Try this JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khoorooslary/6DjpT/

You need Javascript to link the ID of drop down to the input radio's

*PS if you aren't familiar with JSFiddle, look on the bottom right window to see the demo and play with it*

**HTML Code**

```
<form>

    <input type="radio" id="rd_one" name="rd" value="1"  checked="checked"/>
    <input type="radio" id="rd_two" name="rd" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="rd_three" name="rd" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" id="rd_four" name="rd" value="4" />
    <hr />

    <select id="ByIdDemo">
        <option>Select By Id Demo</option>
        <option value="one">Option 1</option>
        <option value="two">Option 2</option>
        <option value="three">Option 3</option>
        <option value="four">Option 4</option>
    </select>

    <hr />

    <select id="ByValue">
        <option>Select By Value Demo</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$(function() {

    $("#ByIdDemo").on('change',function() {
        var sel = this;
        $("form input").each(function(eli,el) {
            var id = "rd_"+ sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
            el.checked = el.id == id;
            $(el).attr("checked",  el.checked ? "checked" : null);
        });
    });


     $("#ByValue").on('change',function() {
        var sel = this;
        $("form input").each(function(eli,el) {
            el.checked = el.value == sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
            $(el).attr("checked",  el.checked ? "checked" : null);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks That Helped... Though my actual problem is solved by : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343533/update-partial-view-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

please try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#ddCurrencyId').change(function() {
         $('#CM' + $(this).val()).trigger('click');
     });
});
```

I really need to see more of the HTML Markup After you have ran the project to see Values/HTML of Radio buttons..

Im guessing the value of the dropdown will be 1, 2 or 3, that is why i'm saying `SELECT the ID: CM + DropDownValue` in the code..

Comment: Thanks Indeed the value can be random generated. It got solved, see my another question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343533/update-partial-view-with-ajax