# Update Partial View with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view with the following details,

**_PartialTEST.cshtml**

```
@model FreeLance.Web.Models.PArtialTESTModel

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D1, "true", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g1", @checked = "true" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD1, @Model.V1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D2, "false", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g2" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD2, @Model.V1) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D3, "false", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g3" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD3, @Model.V1)
```

Which is Used in another View,

**MainTEST.cshtml**

```
<div id="partialDIV">
       @{
           @Html.Partial("_PartialTEST", Model)
       }                           
</div>
```

Now During an Event I am trying to get the new values using **AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: href,               
                traditional: true,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: { DID: DID },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#partialDIV').html(data);
                },
                error: function (arg, data, value) {

                }
            });
```

Now though "data" has all the values, I am unable to get the partial view rendered. Any help, What I am missing here?

Comment: Try this ` data: { "DID": DID },`

Comment: Thanks for the help but, I am able to hit the ajax method with the value DID and also getting back to Success part of the Ajax, with the Model values, So After that I may be missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Server side Use this Code to Return your Partial View::

```
    public PartialViewResult MainTEST()
    {
        var model = new FreeLance.Web.Models.PArtialTESTModel();
        return PartialView("_PartialTEST.cshtml",model);
    }
```

and in you AJAX on Client Side do some changes on its success::

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: href,               
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { DID: DID },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;

                $('#partialDIV').empty();
                $('#partialDIV').html(data);
            },
            error: function (arg, data, value) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Great Thanks, As @Jojy mentioned I also should add the data type as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Change your AJAX query by adding datatype as 'html'

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: href,               
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        datatype : "html",
        data: { DID: DID },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

            $('#partialDIV').empty();
            $('#partialDIV').html(data);
        },
        error: function (arg, data, value) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I did try with that bro :)

Comment: what is the data that gets returned?

Comment: Thanks, In my revised solution as mentioned by Rahul, I indeed need to  mention datatype as HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look in these post:

http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.in/2011/05/aspnet-mvc-razor-render-partial-view.html

http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.in/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-render-partial-view-using.html

Comment: Thanks for the help :) There is some good info their with @Ajax.ActionLink. That is pretty new to me...

Comment: Link is now dead

Answer (score 1):

You just missed a single parameter datatype , i.e. You have to specify the datatype as the type which the controller function returns, Since you are expecting partialview, you have to specify datatype as html.

```
    .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: href, 
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            datatype:'html',
            data: { DID: DID },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $('#partialDIV').html(data);
            },
            error: function (arg, data, value) {

            }
        });
```

This can solve your issue

Comment: Thanks Hamid, also from the code behind, I was returning a json, instead of an Action result.