# Why Jquery unable to fire events after Ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET project, I have a partial class where I have three radio buttons.

I have a partial view with the following details,

**_PartialTEST.cshtml**

```
@model FreeLance.Web.Models.PArtialTESTModel

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D1, "true", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g1", @checked = "true" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD1, @Model.V1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D2, "false", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g2" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD2, @Model.V1) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.D3, "false", new { Name = "test1", @id = "g3" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MSGD3, @Model.V1)
```

Which is Used in another View,

**MainTEST.cshtml**

```
<div id="partialDIV">
       @{
           @Html.Partial("_PartialTEST", Model)
       }                           
</div>
```

I am reloading the content of the div, using AJAX, for an event to update radio buttons with new values

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: href,               
                traditional: true,
                async: false,
                datatype: "html",
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: { DID: DID },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#partialDIV').empty();
                    $('#partialDIV').html(data);
                },
                error: function (arg, data, value) {

                }
            });
```

It calls following code from code behind.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GETRADIOVALUES(string CID)
        {
            TESTModel NewModel = new TESTModel();
            ....
            return PartialView("_DurationDetails",NewModel);
        }
```

Now it loads radio buttons correctly with new values.

However the real problem is any of the Jquery events get called.

For example

```
$('#g1').change(function() {
});
```

or even,

```
$("input[name=test1]:radio").change(function () {

});
```

Please help me why these Jquery events are not firing, though the IDs are available in View Source also.

Comment: you ajax function have something which should not be there like `dataType:html` then `contentType:"application/json"`.

Comment: Dear Jai , I am not sure whether you put a negative vote for that? Plz look into this question, and apparently I was missing the datatype [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343533/update-partial-view-with-ajax)

Comment: NO i have not downvoted the question.

Comment: That's Oky may I know why did you tell these two options are not required.

Comment: i have not mentioned to remove both of them but you have to carry only the required one so in your case you can omit the contentType:json.

Comment: Thanks Jai will remove it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `event delegation` for dynamically created elements.

```
 $(document).on('change',"input[name=test1]:radio",function () {
     //code here
 });
```

Comment: Dear Milind what if I want to check this condition,  if($('#g1').is(':checked'))

Comment: do you want it only for one element that have id `g1`??. If yes then just change `input[name=test1]:radio` to `#g1`

Comment: Will it check whether the #g1 radio Button is checked, or will it fire for both check and un check?

Comment: the change event will trigger in both cases. if you want something to be executed on checked then use condition `if($(this').is(':checked'))` or `if($('#g1').is(':checked'))`

Comment: Well That the issue, It is not firing for #g1 after dynamic update :(

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$('#partialDIV').on('change', '#g1', function(){
 ....
});
```

also take a look [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks Jogesh, But Milind was just a few seconds faster... And thanks for the link...